# ImageView in Table View Cell cutting off Label (Autolayout)

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiimageview, autolayout

I have a **Table View Cell** that I'm using **AutoLayout** on, but **can't figure out how to get the Image View in the right place**.

**Known Constants:**

- Top `UIImageView` size and position on screen
- Bottom `UIImageView` size

**Known Non-Constants:**

- Description Label amount of text
- Time Label amount of text
- Description Label amount of text

I'm running into trouble because I have a constraint for the bottom image view to have a bottom constraint of 10, but that seems to be pushing the ImageView up to where its cutting off the second lines of the Description Label if there are any.

Can you help me? Let me know if you need me to post all of my constraints, because I'd be happy to do that. Thanks!

UPDATE: per Carousel's response, which of the two are you talking about "Add width and height constraint for Description Label" in?

[image]
or
[image]

**UPDATE 2:**

Hoping to try to make this more on topic and let you all know what I did on this.  I definitely used the accepted answer below, but I also pinned the image to the sides of the Table View Cell too, which helped the part where images would be getting cut off.
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add width and height constraint for Description Label, and you are good to go.

Comment: Thanks for the response!  Are you talking about doing it in the Pin menu or in the Size Inspector?  I added screenshots in my original question relating to what I have right now for them: No constraints in the Pin menu for Description Label, but I do have the numbers put in the Size Inspector for X,Y,W,H for the Description Label.

Comment: The only other constraints that are on Description Label are from selecting Headline, Time, Description all at once and checking the Leading and Trailing Edges boxes.  Also I have Vertical Spacing between Description Label and the bottom Image View.  Is that what you're talking about?

Comment: I have uploaded an [example](https://www.dropbox.com/s/0vh2hrmv5ckhulf/NewTableView.zip?dl=0), which simulates your UIControl structure in tableview cell.

Comment: Cool I'm gonna try it out right now!

Comment: Gonna mark your answer as correct even before I try that out because I'm assuming it works and you also went the extra mile by uploading an example.  Seriously awesome!

Comment: Does it work for you?

Comment: Still trying to get it working for me.  Obviously yours works, so I'm going nuts trying to get mine exactly like yours.  I'll let ya know, thanks again!